# I was using a remote ubuntu server through ssh and typed shutdown. now I can't get back in. any Advice?

Tags: ssh, shutdown

I was using a remote ubuntu server through ssh and typed shutdown. now I can't get back in. Is there anyway to start a remote server through ssh?

Comment: Server needs to be turned on now....if you have some access physical or over web interface...you need to turn it on.

Comment: Well only other chance would be if you have a `wake up on LAN` configured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to tell the admin of the remote server what you did and ask him to start the server.